# How to update the state in functional component using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I am creating a functional React component using Hook. In my component I use Axios API to fetch the data from the REST API. This is my code, however the problem is the state variable is  NOT updated when I pass the data received from the server. I used useEffect Hook where I employed axios API to fetch the data.
The data is received however when I used this data to set the state variable, the state variable return error that it is not defined, not sure what I'm missing. Any comments please. I have noticed that the `setState(data)` does not update the state variable. However later when I checked the state variables in the click event of the button I found the state variables were update from the fetched data. Please see the code in the click handler the state variable returns value. However, I want it to be update without clicking of the button. Any comment please.

```
function TestState() 
{  
       
    const [count, setCount] = useState(10);
    const [state, setState] = useState({
          booktitle:"",
          Author:"",
          Year:1990,
          Topic:"",
          format:""
          

    })
     
     
    function Setstatewithdata(data)
    {
    
        console.log("state vrb",state, "count",count)
       
       
        setState(state);
        console.log("after state vrb",state, "count",count)
        }
    
      useEffect(() => 
    {
    console.log("useeffect count is ",count,"author",state.author)
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/allbooks")
            .then(res => {
                 console.log("data received "+res.data)
                res.data.map(function(currentstate, i){
                    console.log("data.res"+currentstate.Author)
            })  
                Setstatewithdata(res.data)
            } //            
            )
            .catch(err => {
              console.log("error has occured"+ err)
            })
    }, [])

     const ClickHandle=() =>
     {
     
     console.log("state vrb",state.Author, "count",count) 
     setCount(count + 1)
      console.log(state)
   
     
    }
     return (
   
     <div className="App-header">
     <form>
      <div>
                <h3>Data Received List</h3>
              
            </div>
     <h1>Click Counts are {count}</h1>
      <button type= "button" onClick={ClickHandle}>Click me{count} </button> 
      </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
     export default TestState
```

Comment: Just `setState(data)` ? Because `setState([state, data])` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: i want get url `api` realy for test

Answer (score 0):

The assignment of `setState([state, data]);` will let ES6 create an array of the state and the data object and will try to assign it to the state, which normally wouldn't be a problem but since your initial assignment to state is an object and not an array, the type of assignment for the state will have a mismatch and it will prone for an error. try to use `setState(data);` and see if it does the trick.

Comment: I did try setState(data) in useeffect but still it does not update the state variable. for example when i checked my state variable soon after setState(data) , the state was not showing updated value, however when i checked the state values in the click event of the  buttom i found state values updates. it appears that state values are not updated in usereffect but then how to do it ? any comments

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine and I will take that the states change, as you said. The problem is related with your `Setstatewithdata` function, which is supposed to be a way to see if your `state` state changed or not. The thing is, that the `state` state is not been updated until the method/function execution is finished, so you are seeing the previous value in the console the two times you `console.log(..`. So in order to see what new data is assigned to the `state` state, your function should look like this:

```
function Setstatewithdata(data) {
    console.log("state vrb", state, "count", count);
    setState(state);
    console.log("after state vrb", data, "count", count);
}
```